# Docker Security - Allow Interactive Shell?

Tags: security, docker, rancher

I am running my application on a tomcat inside a Docker container as a non-root user tomcat (All running within a Rancher Environment).

So, of course, when you do

```
$ docker exec -ti <containderId> /bin/bash
```

you end up having a shell inside the container

```
tomcat@bd57f0210601:/opt/tomcat$
```

recently we had a security audit (pentest) checking all our aspects of the application stack. The tester created an issue that having **an interactive shell would be a security concern!**?

While I do not completely disagree, but unsuccessful trying to find good research/best practices/security concerns on that particular issue, I am still wondering about the pros and cons?

Can anyone share some information on that topic, from their own experience or just a link?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if a malicious actor is in your network and can access docker daemon, that is a security issue by itself. Being able to open a shell in a container is nothing compared to that.

Comment: To be clear, if you can `docker` anything, you have full and unrestricted root access on the host.  (And if you can `docker exec`, you can `docker exec -u 0` to get a root shell in the container.)  Is there a more specific concern you're trying to address?

Comment: yes, absolutely correct, if your network is compromised you're doomed no matter what :-)

I'm trying to find if there is a concern at all. I can't figure out if it makes a difference or not. Since if I'm on the VM it doesn't matter if the shell of a running container is accessible or not, because I can easily start a new one with the option -it and have access again. I probably would have to remove the shell from the user's profile in order to deny it in general, as @mrangry777 has stated below

Answer (score 0):

You can completely remove shell from the image like so:

```
docker exec :id -it /bin/rm -R /bin/*
```

However, if you would like to keep sensitive information from users and allow some kind of access check out:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Comment: thanks. I'm already using secrets. I'm trying to find out the security aspect of users having access to a shell inside a container. Your idea is very interesting.